# svn not detecting changed file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I see there is similar questions, but it appears the source of the problem differs.

I have a file myfile.fsb that is part of an svn repository, when the file is build (by fmod, a sound processing application) this file is regenerated,

- the date modified changes when it is build again ( as expected)
- the .svn folder hasn't been over-written
- current svn client is 1.7.9, current tortoise svn version 1.7.12 64 bits
- tested this in at least 4 different machines (all of them using tortoise svn)
- the file in question is **not** on svn:ignore

I tried removing the file and restoring. It is a big repository so I am in the process of checking out in a new location and see if that happens there too

Any ideas why I can't see /commit the updated file?

Comment: Is the file really different? If only the timestamp changed but the content is the same then this is normal.

Comment: Going to need more info than this.  Say you do an md5sum on the files do they differ?  Subversion looks at timestamp and filesize and if both match it will assume the file is unchanged, but you're saying the timestamp changed.  Both of those Subversion versions are a tad old, might be worth trying newer versions as well.